# php laravel how to include additional library after it was installed with composer

Tags: php, laravel, shared-libraries

In a php laravel 9 project i try to use  this library:

https://packagist.org/packages/cnlpete/image-metadata-parser

I added it to composer configuration:

```
composer require cnlpete/image-metadata-parser
```

Then I add it in controller to be able to find the class.

I tried like this :

```
//add this into controller:
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use cnlpete\image-metadata-parser;
```

And I get error
syntax error, unexpected token "-", expecting "," or ";"

Then I also added in config/app.php this:

```
'aliases' => [

       'ImageMetadataParser' => cnlpete\image-metadata-parser\imageMetadataParser::class,
  ],
```

I see the path to the library after it was installed by composer is: myappname/vendor/cnlpete/image-metadata-parser/imageMetadataParser.php

If I use just like this without other configuration:

```
$imageparser = new vendor\cnlpete\image-metadata-parser\ImageMetadataParser(....);
```

I get error:
Error
Class "App\Http\Controllers\vendor\cnlpete\image" not found

How to include this library in the controller to be able to use it?

Answer (score 1):

The class doesn't have a namespace. You don't need to import or alias the class. Composer makes it usable project-wide.

Simply use it as if it were imported:

```php
$imageparser = new ImageMetadataParser('file');
```

Since you're in Laravel, you also don't need to require the autoload.php file a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Your system loads `imageMetadataParser.php` in

```
App\Http\Controllers\vendor\cnlpete\image
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^
```

---

Define path as

```
base_path().'./vendor/autoload.php'; 
or
base_path('./vendor/autoload.php');
```

> `base_path()` refers to the project root.

---

Or load it as a custom library.

1. [Creating Your Own Laravel Custom Package: A Step-by-Step Guide](https://adevait.com/laravel/how-to-create-a-custom-package-for-laravel)
2. [Custom Laravel Packages](https://kirschbaumdevelopment.com/insights/custom-laravel-packages)

Comment: Did not solved the problem yet. I followed guide2 "Custom Laravel packages" and I added in composer.json in autoload this: "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
      "cnlpete\\image-metadata-parser\\": "packages/cnlpete/image-metadata-parser/"
        }
    }, Then I try to use like this: require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
namespace cnlpete\image-metadata-parser;